# Multiple Pseudo Classes on a Single Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Is the following CSS syntax valid?

```
a:first-child:hover { background-color: transparent; }
```

If so, what is the compatibility as far as browsers? For example, is it compatible in IE8, IE6+, Firefox 4, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combo `first-child` and `:hover` is correct(IE6 recognize only last pseudo-class in the chain):

```css
div span:first-child:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works but also take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: This isn't so much an issue of IE6 not recognizing multiple pseudo-classes in a chain as that it doesn't recognize `:first-child`. It does sound like a reasonable claim, though.