# Is there any way to active "after" pseudo-element while same element being hovered?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a picture as a border-bottom in the list menu during hover the li element.

```
li:hover li:after{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x65");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center bottom;
    }
```

any way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Pseudo Classes on a Single Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331619/multiple-pseudo-classes-on-a-single-selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close but the way you've written it causes the `li:after` to override `li:hover` You can combine the two.

`li:hover:after { ... }` - changes the after pseudo-class when the li hovers.

`li:after:hover { ... }` - would only change the pseudo-class when the after itself is hovered.

Remember you should add these AFTER you define the default state just like any other hover definition.